create a button in the application when you click on a create button
Good evening,
I would like to know if it is possible to put a create button in the application and when users click on it, it should create a button next to it that will serve as a storage category.
Thanks in advance
Create a button but imposssible.

Welcome to SO!
Please [edit] your question to include some code, providing a [MRE]

The question explanation it not enough but as I understand :
First you need to store the buttons in the list
List<Widget> buttons = <Widget>[];

Create the button widget you want to be created, for example:

class CreatedButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const CreatedButtonWidget({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        color: Colors.orange,
        child: const Text("Button"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Then the Widget that will add the new button is ListView.builder as you can use the buttons list with it :
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: buttons.length,
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return buttons[index];
   },
 ),

Then create the method that will add the new widget to the UI:
void _createNewButton() {
    setState(
      () {
        buttons.add(
          const CreatedButtonWidget(),
        );
      },
    );
  }

finally create a static button that when user press on it, it will create the new button :
MaterialButton(
  onPressed: () {
    _createNewButton();
  },
  color: Colors.cyan,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
   ),
   child: const Text("Create Button"),
 ),

Full code:
class CreateButtonWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateButtonWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<CreateButtonWidget> createState() => _CreateButtonWidgetState();
}

class _CreateButtonWidgetState extends State<CreateButtonWidget> {
  List<Widget> buttons = <Widget>[];

  void _createNewButton() {
    setState(
      () {
        buttons.add(
          const CreatedButtonWidget(),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Button generator"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan[200],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: [
              buttons.isEmpty
                  ? const Text("No Buttons yet")
                  : Expanded(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: context.screenHeight * .08,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: buttons.length,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return buttons[index];
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
            ],
          ),
          Center(
            child: MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _createNewButton();
              },
              color: Colors.cyan,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
              child: const Text("Create Button"),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CreatedButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const CreatedButtonWidget({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        color: Colors.orange,
        child: const Text("Button "),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Hope that's help you !!

Thank you very much.
I am not far from the truth. I have an error:
Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#dd25b relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1972 pos 12: 'hasSize'

You are welcome !! please make sure that the SizedBox that wrap the ListView.builder has height && width ,  in the above code the screenHeight is an extension I created you can give it a direct value.
